# Grid is not correct with imshow matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, plot, imshow

I am trying to make a confusion matrix plot, or just any plot with quadrants and something in it. I used imshow.

```
cm = [[370288,  5190],
       [ 2213,   6758]]

with plt.style.context("seaborn-white"):

    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='none', vmin=1, vmax=1)
    classNames = ['no churn','churn']
    ax.set_title('Confusion Matrix',fontsize=20, fontweight='bold', color='indigo')
    ax.set_ylabel('actual',fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
    ax.set_xlabel('predicted',fontsize=15, fontweight='bold')
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classNames))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classNames)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks, classNames, rotation=90)
    plt.grid(color='indigo', linestyle='-', linewidth=5)
    s = [['TN','FP'], ['FN', 'TP']]



    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(2):
            plt.text(j,i, str(s[i][j])+" = "+annot[i][j], size=12, ha='center', va='center')
    plt.show()
```

Unfortunately I don't manage to make the grid right. If I add

```
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, 1.5, 1))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, 1.5, 1))
```

then the grid is correct but the x and y axis labels are not centered anymore and right and left border are not bold. How can I have bold borders and the correct grid that divides the whole plot into four quadrants?

Comment: Use e.g. major ticks for the ticks and labels, and minor ticks for the grid. Or vice versa.

Comment: How would this work?